# Asp.net MVC 4 Code First Return Specific Fields from Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Been stuck on this for a while so i thought i would ask.  I am sure there is something simple i am missing here.  Trying to learn Asp.net mvc 4 on my own by building a simple app.

Here is the model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Note> notes;
    public ICollection<Note> Notes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.notes ?? (this.notes = new List<Note>());
        }
    }
}

public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}

    public Note()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
    }
}
```

I call this method in a repository from the controller:

```
 public IQueryable<Note> GetAll()
    {
        var query = _db.Notes.Include(x => x.Category).Include(y => y.Tags);
        return query;
    }
```

On the home controller i am trying to return a list of all the notes and wanted to include the category name that it belongs to as well as the tags that go with the note.  At first the did not show up so i read some tutorials about eager loading and figured out how to get them to show.

However, my method is not that efficient.  The mini-profiler is barking at me for duplicate queries because the navigation properties for category and tags are sending queries for the notes again.  IS there any way to just return the properties i need for the category and tag objects?

I have tried several methods with no luck.  I was hoping i could do something like this:

```
var query = _db.Notes.Include(x => x.Category.Name).Include(y => y.Tags.Name);
```

But i get an error:  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

I have seen that error before that was caused by some missing using statements so i already double checked that.

Any suggestions?  Thanks for the help

Comment: You cannot eager load just subset of fields for relations. Your first query should be OK and it should not cause any additional queries to the database.

Comment: Looks like it's time to think about DTO's.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look into DTO's for sure.  I read up a little and that seems like a better way to get data to the view.  Is that better than a View Model or are they the same thing?